# .htaccess RewriteRule from '?' to '#!'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I RewriteRule from page `index2.php?q=xxx` to `index2.php#!q=xxx`?

I tired code, but still not work. So is it possible? Or I need relay on js `window.location.hash`, how? Thanks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index2.php#!q=([^/]*)$ index2.php?q=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you can't match # using htaccess. 
try use other symbol instead it.

Comment: Fragment Identifier (the `#` and everything after it) is **client side only** and is not even sent to a server by browser. Even if it sill be sent somehow (using custom code (PHP,ASP.NET ect), for example) it will either be rejected by server or silently stripped from the request.

Comment: It makes *little sense* to rewrite `?` to `#!` or vice-versa. The browser *will never send* the fragment portion of the URI (the `#` and anything after). If the problem is described better, then there will likely be better answers, some possibly including client-side approaches.

Comment: @Kakashi, so how many symbols allowed? thanks.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite `?`  to `#!`, or the inverse ? (The question and the title seem to disagree.)

Comment: @yuli, you can use `[!,@,$,*,+,-,(,),{,},:,;^,~]` and other. 
try removing the fragment in you regex: `RewriteRule ^index2.php!q=([^/]*)$ index2.php?q=$1`

Comment: @Kakashi, Thanks, so waiting for `window.location.hash` answer.

Comment: @arnaud576875, yes, I want rewitre url from `? to #!`. sorry for not a good title. so do you have any idea can help me out? i tried make some thing as ajax crawling url `http://code.google.com/intl/en-us/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to redirect `?q=` to `#!q=`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(q=.*)$
RewriteRule ^index2.php index2.php#!$1 [NE,L,R]
```

If you want to redirect from `#!q=` to `?q=`, you have to use JavaScript:

```
if( window.location.hash.match(/^#!(q=.*)$/) )
    window.location.replace( "?" + RegExp.$1 ); // redirect
```

Comment: thanks, but this still not work, my url change still like `index2.php?q=text`, BTW, i use `form METHOD GET` pass value to current page. I have canceled any `htaccess` rewrite.

Comment: i want change from `?` to `#!`, not `#!` to `?`.

Comment: thanks for update your answer, this worked for url address. But I can not get value use <?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>

Comment: To access `$_GET` you need to use `?q=`. With `#!q=` you cannot use `$_GET`, since Hashes aren't sent to server, you need to work with JavaScript/Ajax instead of PHP.

Comment: Ok, Thax, i will try it by `JavaScript/Ajax`, so `.htaccess` can do this work.